# Enumerate all DLLs dependencies C#

Tags: c#, dll

I need to enumerate all libraries (dll) that a running application is using (I call it for example "example").

(specifically I need to check if in an application it was injected a third part dll)

I've tried this code:

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();

foreach (Process process in processes)
{            
    if (process.ProcessName=="example")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PID:  " + process.Id);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + process.ProcessName);
        foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(module.FileName);
        }
    }
}
```

but it list only the "WINDOWS\system32" folder DLLs **without showing even the "example" software dlls**.

What the code find is only:

...\System32\ntdll.dll 
...\System32\wow64.dll 
...\System32\wow64win.dll 
...\System32\wow64cpu.dll

How can I solve that?

Thanks.